# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/'

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to use preg_match to return all the URL's that are inclosed in "  " in a page source code.

The code I am using is

```
preg_match('"http://(.+?)\"', $code, $matches);
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/' in .... on line 13
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
preg_match('~"http://(.*)"~iU', $code, $matches);
```

Your issue was you need delimiters (I chose ~) to use with the pattern. See the [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/preg_match) man page for more information.

Comment: Wait, seriously? You can chose whatever delimiter you want? I've only ever used `/` and there are definitely cases (like this) where using something else would be so much more convenient! +1!

Comment: Thanks... Worked like a charm!

Comment: @JGB146: Well, *almost* any. You can choose any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character as delimiter.

Comment: ~ is particularly useful if you're matching url-encoded strings as ~ is a character that doesn't need encoding and won't be in the regex, i.e. [^!#$&'()*+,/:;=?@[\\]]+

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
preg_match('"http:\/\/(.+?)\"', $code, $matches);
```